# how to initialize a static member in cpp file only situation via a

Tags: c++

I have a class in a cpp file. There is no header file in my case:

```
class MyClassATest
{
     static Logging &logger = Logging::getInstance();

     static void testMethodA()
     {
          logger.logDebug(....);

     }

};
```

I tried several different ways try to make the first statement works:

```
constexpr static Logging &logger = Logging::getInstance();
static Logging const &logger = Logging::getInstance();
constexpr static Logging const &logger = Logging::getInstance();
```

Is there a way to initialize that logger variable in my case?

**EDIT:**

Following are the results in different cases:

```
error: field initializer is not constant
         constexpr const static Logging &logger = Logging::getInstance();

error: field initializer is not constant
         constexpr static const BMLogging &logger = BMLogging::getInstance();

error: field initializer is not constant
         constexpr static BMLogging const &logger = BMLogging::getInstance();

error: field initializer is not constant
         constexpr static BMLogging &logger = BMLogging::getInstance();
```

Comment: What exactly is not working about your solution now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize it outside the class, like this:

```
// This goes in your CPP file at any point after the class declaration
Logging& MyClassATest::logger(Logging::getInstance());
```

Alternatively, you could put initialization in a static member function:

```
static Logging& logger() {
    // Make a function-static variable instead of a class-static one
    static Logging &loggerInstance(Logging::getInstance());
    return loggerInstance;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant Logging& MyClassATest::logger(Logging::getInstance());

Comment: @AtlasC1 You are right, thanks! By the way, when you see silly errors like this, feel free to edit or to suggest an edit: I quickly approve these when I see them on my answers. Thank you very much!

Comment: the compile error goes away but I get link error: undefined reference to `Logging::getInstance()' for that line. I checked result, I saw the libloggint.a was there.

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA That's strange: a link error usually indicates that the library is not there, or that the header does not match the library. It is possible with some linkers that the order in which you mention libraries needs to be changed, but that's assuming that you are building a library, not an executable, and then try linking it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Right now there are two modules: logging and common, they have each other's reference. If I change the link sequence, I get different error telling me some common methods not defined in logging. previous error is saying some logging methods cannot be found in common. any idea?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA If you get a different error when you switch the order of modules when you link, you've got a circular reference going on. Fixing this requires code restructuring: you need to split one of the modules (or both modules) in a way that there is no circular dependencies among the resulting modules.

Answer (score 1):

In class member initialization is applicable to integral types only. So, you have to initialize it out of class.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. With C++11, in-class member initialization applies to static, non-integral types, given they are constexpr. Furthermore, non-static members can be initialized in-class even if they are not a constant expression (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).